# Creating a Method that Accepts a String Format Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do you create a method in Objective-C that accepts a NSString format (using the comma seperated list list of arguments to substitute into the format). Something like:

```
// Hello Kevin
NSString *name = @"Kevin";
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", name];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [Variadic Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and in Objective-C you can write something like the following:

```
- (NSString *) stringWithFormat:(NSString ) format, ... { }
```

You can use this [excellent example for Objective-C variadic functions](http://www.numbergrinder.com/node/35) for more detail.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, couldn't find it cause I didn't know the name for it. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

These are variadic arguments.

```
@interface Foo {}
-(void)myVariadicMethod:...;
@end

@implementation Foo

-(void)myVariadicMethod:...
{
 va_list arguments;
    // _cmd is a hidden argument all Objective-C methods receive
 va_start(arguements, _cmd);

 // same as for a C function: use va_arg

 va_end(arguments);
}

@end
```

The ellipsis must *always* be the last "argument" your method accepts.

Comment: Thanks for the great example! Appreciate the help!